# Инициализация vector в конструкторе

Tags: c++, vector, конструктор

Здравствуйте! Мне требуется инициализировать в конструкторе структуру типа vector(map(int,double))  (с её помощью реализуется разрежённая матрица) на основании данных о вычислительной сетке из объекта mesh. Внутри конструктора всё происходит замечательно, то есть если в конце конструктора вывести на экран размер этого вектора и его содержимое, то там всё в порядке и он не пустой. Однако после возврата в основную программу размер вектора оказывается равным нулю, то есть он становится пустым. В чём может быть дело?

класс описан в файле operators.h

```
#include "mesh.h"

// stores the matrix of the operator in CSR format using vector of maps
class Operator {
public:
    int     N;          // number of rows = number of columns = N
    std::vector< std::map< int, double > > x;   //sparse matrix Operator_x
    Operator(Mesh &mesh);       // constructor
};
```

его реализация в файле operators.cpp

```
#include "operators.h"
#include "mesh.h"

// constructs matrix for grad, div, rot operator
Operator::Operator(Mesh &mesh) {
    int i,j;
    // number of rows = number of nodes
    N = mesh.n;

    // allocate memory for matrix
    std::vector< std::map< int, double > > x(N);    //sparse matrix Operator_x

    // fill the matrix with values
    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < mesh.node[i].nb.size() ; j++ )
        {
            x[i][mesh.node[i].nb[j].num] = mesh.node[i].nb[j].norm_x / (2. * mesh.node[i].S);
        }
    }

    // здесь всё хорошо, выводится ненулевой размер и правильные элементы
    std::cout << "x.size=" << x.size() << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (auto it = x[i].begin(); it != x[i].end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << "i=" << i << " j=" << it->first << " value=" << it->second << "\n";
    }
};
```

И наконец вызов из main(), с которым проблема

```
Operator A12(mesh);
//вот здесь выводится нулевой размер
std::cout << "x.size=" << A12.x.size() << "\n";
```

Comment: Вы в конструкторе завели локальный вектор x. Вот здесь: `std::vector< std::map< int, double > > x(N);    //sparse matrix Operator_x`, он будет существовать только внутри конструктора. Замените на `x.resize(N)`. А ещё лучше на `this->x.resize(N)`

Comment: @vegorov спасибо, работает! а можете тогда, пожалуйста, пояснить, в чём разница между `x.resize(N)` и `this->x.resize(N)` ?

Comment: а никакой разницы, просто для наглядности. Обычно приватные поля класса обозначают с префиксом или суффиксом, `m_`, к примеру, и тогда в конструкторе увидев `m_x.resize(N)` сразу понятно, что это обращение к полю класса, а не работа с локальной переменной. Ну и если бы вы всё таки завели локальную переменную x, то `this->x` - это обращение к полю класса, а просто `x` - уже к локальной переменной (а за отсутствием оной - к полю класса).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что надо не

```
Operator::Operator(Mesh &mesh) {
...
   std::vector< std::map< int, double > > x(N);
```

а примерно так:

```
Operator::Operator(Mesh &mesh):x(N) {
...
// Это не нужно!! Это локальная переменная, а не член!
// std::vector< std::map< int, double > > x(N);
```

Comment: Там `resize` нужен, потому что далее по коду идёт в цикле обращение к `i`-ому элементу вектора

Comment: @vegorov Это же неважно - что делается дальше в конструкторе, так и делается, я писал только об одной удаленной строке (вернее, о переносе в список инициализации).

Comment: упс, сори, не заметил `:x(N)`